# Swing HTML rendering changing when using BufferedImage

Tags: java, html, image, swing

The behaviour of labels containing HTML seems to change when they are first painted to a BufferedImage. In the code that follows, only the first two lines of the text are displayed. The number of lines increases as more `<br>` breaks are added. It seems to be calculating the number of lines pre-wrapping rather than post-wrapping.

If the label is painted directly to the component's graphic (i.e. the commented line) then it works fine.

Why would the behaviour change if it's painted to a `BufferedImage`'s graphic rather than a `JComponent`'s.

```
public class HTMLFormatting {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("HTML Formatting");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 330));
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(200, 300, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                JLabel label = new JLabel("<html>A piece of text that requires wrapping because "
                    + "it is too long for a single line of a label and is a test of formatting."
                    + "<br>A second line.</html>");
                label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
                JPanel layoutPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                layoutPanel.setSize(new Dimension(200, 300));
                layoutPanel.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                layoutPanel.doLayout();
                label.paint(image.getGraphics());
                g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
//                label.paint(g);
            }
        };
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
        frame.add(exitButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        exitButton.addActionListener(ev -> System.exit(0));

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A width can be set for the `body` using HTML styles (CSS).  This in turn will determine the number of lines to render and, from that, the preferred height of the label.

Setting the width in CSS avoids the need to compute where line breaks should occur in (or the best size of) the label.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class FixedWidthLabel {

    public static void main(String[] srgs) {
        final String s = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean eu nulla urna. Donec sit amet risus nisl, a porta enim. Quisque luctus, ligula eu scelerisque gravida, tellus quam vestibulum urna, ut aliquet sapien purus sed erat. Pellentesque consequat vehicula magna, eu aliquam magna interdum porttitor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed sollicitudin sapien non leo tempus lobortis. Morbi semper auctor ipsum, a semper quam elementum a. Aliquam eget sem metus.";
        final String html1 = "<html><body style='width: ";
        final String html2 = "px'>";

        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                        null, new JLabel(html1 + "200" + html2 + s));
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                        null, new JLabel(html1 + "300" + html2 + s));
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

[image] [image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am aware of the use of widths in the HTML. I asked the question because I was interested in an explanation of the different behaviour rather than how to change it.

Comment: The size of a `JLabel` displayed as a component will more typically be controlled by the layout of the parent container. If it constrains the width, the HTML formatted text is likely to be wrapped. If you're wanting to investigate further, include a [mcve] of the *other* behaviour.